# How to push background task before starting FastAPI application?

Tags: python, asynchronous, task, fastapi

I want to create a background task that will keep running throughout the app's lifetime.

This is what I've tried so far:

```py
async def my_task():
    # work in background

@app.get('/push_task')
def push_task(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    background_tasks.add_task(my_task)
```

But, in this way, I must execute a `GET` request, in order to add the background task.

I know about `lifespan` evetns, but I can`t use` BackgroundTasks` inside. For instance:

```py
@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    background_tasks.add_task(my_task) # don`t work
```

Answer (score 2):

From: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/2713

```
class BackgroundTask:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    async def my_task():
        pass #work in background

bgtask = BackgroundTask()

@app.on_event('startup')
def on_startup():
    asyncio.create_task(bgtask.my_task())
```

Depending on your specific use case you might need to tweak this a little.

Comment: It is deprecated see: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/events/#alternative-events-deprecated. The recommended way to handle the startup and shutdown is using the lifespan parameter of the FastAPI app as described above.